# PHP Zip Code Losing Leading Zero

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing zip codes in a MySQL database as `varchar(10)`. For some reason storing it in one table is not working like the other one. The only difference between the fields is that one is `varchar(10) Nullable`, and one is `varchar(10)`. The `Nullable` column is saving the zip code without a leading zero so `'05415'` becomes `5415`. This is working in the other table just fine. I think they are being stored on the same page, but I can't seem to find the problem. I'm not very good with PHP, so I would really appreciate some help here.

This is the function for registration on the site....the registration table in the db is saving the zip code with the leading 0, so I assume that this works.

```
 $Zip       = strip_tags(trim($_POST['MembersZip']));
    if (strlen($Zip = trim($Zip)) == 0) {
                $isError = true;
                print "<script>$('#MembersZip').addClass('error');</script>";
                print '<div class="errors">Please enter zip / postal code</div>';
            }
    if (strlen($Zip = trim($Zip)) < 5) {
                    $isError = true;
                    print "<script>$('#MembersZip').addClass('error');</script>";
                    print '<div class="errors">Zip code must be at least 5 digits</div>';
                }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ecommerce_addresses ( 
                    ead_postal_code
                ) VALUES (
                    '" . addslashes($Zip) . "'
                )";
```

This is what the process looks like for the orders. This is the table where the leading zero gets deleted before it gets inserted.

```
        $fieldName = "BillingZip";
        $fieldValue = strip_tags($_POST[$fieldName]);
        if (!$fieldValue || strlen($fieldValue = trim($fieldValue)) == 0) {
            $isError = true;
            print "<script>$('#{$fieldName}').addClass('error');</script>";
            print '<div class="errors">Please enter billing zip / postal code</div>';
        } else {
            $this->fields[$fieldName] = $fieldValue;
            $this->record->eod_billing_postal_code = $fieldValue;
        }
    $Zip    = $this->record->eod_billing_postal_code;
    if (strlen($Zip = trim($Zip)) < 5) {
                $isError = true;
                print "<script>$('#BillingZip').addClass('error');</script>";
                print '<div class="errors">Billing Zip Code must be at least 5 digits</div>';
            }
It looks like this line
$newId = $this->record->insert();
is doing the insert, but when I do a var_dump of $this->record, the zip code still shows the leading 0. The only other thing I can think of is that the payment gateway is changing it somehow.


        $paymentType        = urlencode("Authorization");  // 'Sale' or 'Authorization'
        $firstName          = urlencode($this->fields["BillingFirst"]);
        $lastName           = urlencode($this->fields["BillingLast"]); 
        $creditCardType     = urlencode($this->fields["CardType"]); 
        $creditCardNumber   = urlencode($this->fields["CardNumber"]); 
        $padDateMonth       = urlencode(str_pad($this->fields["CardMonth"], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)); 
        $expDateYear        = urlencode($this->fields["CardYear"]); 
        $cvv2Number         = urlencode($this->fields["CardCode"]); 
        $address1           = trim(urlencode($this->fields["BillingAddress"]));
        $address2           = urlencode($this->fields["BillingAddress2"]); 
        $city               = urlencode($this->fields["BillingCity"]); 
        $state              = urlencode($this->fields["BillingState"]); 
        $zip                = urlencode($this->fields["BillingZip"]); 
        $country            = urlencode($CountryCode); // US or other valid country code 
        $amount             = urlencode($this->fields["PurchasedTotal"]); 
        $currencyID         = urlencode($this->siteConfig->cy_code); 
        $ipAddress          = $main->getIP();
        $invoice            = substr($this->fields["CardNumber"],-4,4) . substr($this->fields["BillingZip"],0,4) . substr($this->fields["PurchasedTotal"],0,2);

        $nvpStr = "&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&IPADDRESS=$ipAddress&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
        "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&INVNUM=$invoice&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName".
        "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=USD";
```

To get the zip code to display correctly, I updated the code with this, and the 0 showed up:

```
$zip = str_pad($order->eod_shipping_postal_code, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump($this->fields)`?

Comment: `["ShippingZip"]=> string(5) "05154"` Looks like it is right. hmmm

Comment: @sjagr I also added `var_dump($this->record)` but it still shows the zip code right. I thought this line `$newId = $this->record->insert();` was inserting the data, but if the zip code shows fine when I dump it, then where else could the problem be?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code leading up to the database insert? Did you try doing a raw `INSERT` query using phpMyAdmin or something like that? Does your SQL query use quotations around the value you're inserting?

Comment: No, I haven't tried a raw `INSERT` of data into the db, but I suppose I should. Can I send you the file @sjagr? This process page is huge and if I post the whole function, yikes...

Comment: sure thing, or you can PasteBin it

Comment: I tried going to the PasteBin website, but it's blocked by my company's internet policy. Anyway, I inserted a row straight into the database and the zip codes showed up with the leading zeros. It's definitely in the PHP somewhere.

Comment: The code that is shown looks fine.  It is time to focus some suspicion on how you are viewing the truncated zip code.  How do you view the zip code?:  in code, or from the database?

Comment: The zip code in the database is where I get the deletion of the 0. It shows up on the user's side right, but in the invoice, it prints without that 0 because that is how its getting stored in the database. I thought if I could correct the way it is storing it, that would be better practice than faking it in the code, but I might just have to fake it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I had a guess I would assume that somewhere along the way your variable is being stored as an integer, and if that happens then you would definitely lose that leading '0'. A few options to look at could be looking where the variable is stored and making sure it is stored as a string.

Alternatively, you can always make sure it has 5 numbers in php by using this:

```
str_pad($zip, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

See this: http://www.php.net/str_pad

(Though I would advise that you find where it is being stored as a number over 'faking it' in php. but if you can't find it, this would work)

Comment: I have been looking everywhere to find the problem. What line do I need to replace my code with the code you provided?

Comment: That depends on where it is failing. You would either need to store this as your variable right off the bat so that every place that uses this data has the leading 0, or use this every place that you find that your variable is failing you (but if you find where the variable is failing you, then we could probably hone in better on the problem).

Comment: I think I might have found it. I am going to edit the original post with the code I believe is not getting inserted right.

Comment: I added this to the following lines to get it to display correctly. `$zip = str_pad($order->eod_shipping_postal_code, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` `$shippingInfo .= "{$order->eod_shipping_city}, {$order->eod_shipping_state} &nbsp; {$zip} <br />";`

Answer (score -1):

The data type in the database should be char(5) for the zip-code.